# How to change Spring MVC default controller name and it's location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Java and Spring Framework. Iam using Spring STS 3.1.0.RELEASE with tomcat 7. I creating Spring MVC project by using following directions . File > Spring Template Project > Spring MVC Project. Follwoing is web.xml file code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And following is servlet-contxt.xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.dave.foo" />



</beans:beans>
```

I want ot change default name and location of controller. For this purpose, I create new package org.dave.bar and move IndexController to this package. I also make change as mentioned below in servlet-context.xml file :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.dave.bar" />
```

But I receive 404 error after restaring web server and running the code on this url (http://localhost:8080/bar/). Can some one guied me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the content of the controller class *IndexController*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in the web.xml you will need to define the URL Mapping for which you want the Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet to handle(via request mapped methods in the controllers).
From what I understand in your question you will want to set the URL Mapping as follow (in web.xml)

```
   <servlet>  
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Second,
Under org.dave.foo you will need to place your Spring MVC controllers (classes annotated with @Controller and the URL mapped methods).
In your controller you will need a method mapped to the root of the spring dispatcher servlet URL mapping (defined in web.xml DispatcherServlet):
So for the definition in above you will need a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")  
 public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request,  
         HttpServletResponse response) {  
        ...
  }
```

Note that in general the most specific requests mapping "wins". This means that if you have a request mapping of "/abc" in a controller in addition to the "/" request mapping, then, a request  localhost/myapp/abc will "win" localhost/myapp/

You can take a look at a more detailed example here:
http://www.commonj.com/blogs/2012/11/30/spring-mvc-default-controller-name/

Hope it helped.

Comment: Hi @Rod i am running into same situation badly, could you please help me out on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697899/how-to-map-dynamic-url-prj-noticeopen-2-in-spring-mvc-controller